# Python MySQLdb executemany update on duplicate

Tags: mysql

I am using the executemany function of MySQLdb in python to insert mutliple rows, with on duplicate update. It works as such. But there is a problem. Most of the rows usually need to be updated with one or two inserts happening. I have a autonumber field in that table. And everytime this query runs, the autonumber field jumps even if the actually inserted count is way below the jump. The ids are basically wasted. 
Any clues what is going on here and how to avoid this?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of how the MySQL server handles auto increment fields. The MySQLdb module won't affect the auto increment behavior at all.

[MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/11/29/avoiding-auto-increment-holes-on-innodb-with-insert-ignore/) explains in detail why the gaps happen, and how you can avoid them by using a [mutex table](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/22/mutex-tables-in-sql/). In a nutshell:

```
create table mutex(
    i int not null primary key
);
insert into mutex(i) values (1);

insert into foo(name) select 1 from mutex left outer join foo on foo.name=1 where mutex.i = 1 and foo.name is null;
```

i.e. insert with a sub-select that does a left outer join against the mutex table. Why does this work? If the id is already in the mutex table, it's reused; otherwise, the join produces a NULL, and that triggers the auto-increment.